# why this simple code is not giving the right answer under Compile

Tags: functions, function-construction, compile

I have two sets of inputs that are to be fed to a simple function. The inputs are essentially a set of triangles and the normal for each triangle. The function will compute the gradient about the points (shown in blue). The notebook can be downloaded from the following `Dropbox` Link

https://www.dropbox.com/s/yas32nfccd2dzj4/debug%20code.nb?dl=0

[image]

The two sets of triangles are supposed to be similar (only separated by a translation in space). I compute the area gradient about point `pt1`

```
 grad1 = Block[{ptTri, normal, cross, target, facept, 
 openS = {0., 0., 0.}, closedS = {0., 0., 0.}, source = pt1},
 Do[
 ptTri = opentr1[[i]];
 normal = normOpentr1[[i]];
 cross = If[ptTri[[1]] == source,
 {target, facept} = {ptTri[[2]], ptTri[[-1]]};
 Cross[normal, facept - target],
 {target, facept} = {ptTri[[1]], ptTri[[-1]]};
 Cross[normal, target - facept]
 ];
 openS += (0.5*cross), {i, 1, Length@normOpentr1}];

Do[
ptTri = closedtri1[[j]];
normal = normClosedtr1[[j]];
cross = If[ptTri[[1]] == source,
{target, facept} = {ptTri[[2]], ptTri[[-1]]};
Cross[normal, facept - target],
{target, facept} = {ptTri[[1]], ptTri[[-1]]};
Cross[normal, target - facept]
];
closedS += (0.5*cross), {j, 1, Length@normClosedtr1}];
0.7*closedS + 1*openS
]

(*{0.110728, 0.0466838, 0.752509}*)
```

Likewise if I compute the area gradient about the second point `pt2` I get the same answer.

```
grad2 = Block[{ptTri, normal, cross, target, facept, 
openS = {0., 0., 0.}, closedS = {0., 0., 0.}, source = pt2},
Do[
ptTri = opentr2[[i]];
normal = normOpentr2[[i]];
cross = If[ptTri[[1]] == source,
 {target, facept} = {ptTri[[2]], ptTri[[-1]]};
 Cross[normal, facept - target],
 {target, facept} = {ptTri[[1]], ptTri[[-1]]};
 Cross[normal, target - facept]
 ];
openS += (0.5*cross);, {i, 1, Length@normOpentr2}];
Do[
ptTri = closedtr2[[j]];
normal = normClosedtr2[[j]];
cross = If[ptTri[[1]] == source,
{target, facept} = {ptTri[[2]], ptTri[[-1]]};
Cross[normal, facept - target],
{target, facept} = {ptTri[[1]], ptTri[[-1]]};
Cross[normal, target - facept]
];
closedS += (0.5*cross),{j, 1, Length@normClosedtr2}];
0.7*closedS + 1*openS
]

(*{0.110728, 0.0466838, 0.752509}*)
```

The two answers are quite similar as the difference between `grad1` and `grad2` is `{1.83187*10^-15, -5.55112*10^-16,4.44089*10^-16}`

**HOWEVER**

the same code when under `Compile` does not give the same answers for the two datasets.

```
With[{epcc = 0.7, epco = 1.},
surfaceGradFn2 = 
Compile[{{point, _Real, 1}, {opentr, _Real, 3}, {normalO, _Real,2}, {closedtr, _Real, 3}, {normalC, 
_Real, 2}},
Block[{ptTri, source = point, normal, target, facept, cross, 
 openS = {0., 0., 0.}, closedS = {0., 0., 0.}, nO = normalO, 
 nC = normalC, OT = opentr, CT = closedtr},
Do[
 ptTri = OT[[i]];
 normal = nO[[i]];
 cross = If[ptTri[[1]] == source,
   {target, facept} = {ptTri[[2]], ptTri[[-1]]};
   Cross[normal, facept - target],
   {target, facept} = {ptTri[[1]], ptTri[[-1]]};
   Cross[normal, target - facept]
   ];
 openS += (0.5*cross);
 , {i, 1, Length@nO}];
Do[
 ptTri = CT[[j]];
 normal = nC[[j]];
 cross = If[ptTri[[1]] == source,
   {target, facept} = {ptTri[[2]], ptTri[[-1]]};
   Cross[normal, facept - target],
   {target, facept} = {ptTri[[1]], ptTri[[-1]]};
   Cross[normal, target - facept]
   ];
 closedS += (0.5*cross);
 , {j, 1, Length@nC}];

epcc*closedS + epco*openS
], CompilationTarget -> "C"]
];
```

Though the structure of the code is the same I guess, the outputs are completely different.

```
 surfaceGradFn2[pt1, opentr1, normOpentr1, closedtri1, normClosedtr1]
 (*{-0.0157582, 0.386426, 0.582118} -> this answer is now different but I gave the same inputs as before *)

 surfaceGradFn2[pt2, opentr2, normOpentr2, closedtr2, normClosedtr2]
 (* {0.110728, 0.0466838, 0.752509} -> answer is same as before with the same inputs *)
```

**What am I doing wrong here? Why  does not the compiled code work while the non-compiled version works? I wish to have the compiled version of the code working.**

**also, please ignore what the code intends to do. If you may, kindly look at why the compiled output is different.Thanks and grateful for your help.**

Comment: This could be because compiled code does not support arbitrary precision. What happens in C if you force a number into  a data type that cannot represent that number, is you get a completely different number.

Comment: @C.E. thanks. Can you kindly propose a workaround this. Because the builtin version is a bit slow. I have noticed that the compiled code works for some datasets and not others ! I am surprised that if it is arbitrary precision then the compiled version should not work on other datasets as well. Anyways, what do you recommend, how should I change these numbers to something that compile can understand

Comment: Btw I have used arbitrary precision in other codes while using Compile and it seems to be working fine for those pieces of codes

Comment: ok, I take it back. After looking at your numbers it doesn't seem like they are small or large enough to cause a problem.

Comment: @C.E. Any workaround. Can I somehow convert these to something which does not give this strange behaviour

Answer (score 3):

the problem was in the comparator operator i.e. the `IF` statement. I have used the difference and `Chop` as the fix: `If[Chop[ptTri[[1]] - source, 10^-8] == {0., 0., 0.}...]` rather than `If[ptTri[[1]] == source...]`

the code below now works.

```
ClearAll@surfaceGrad;
With[{epcc = 0.7, epco = 1.},
surfaceGrad = 
Compile[{{point, _Real, 1}, {opentr, _Real, 3}, {normalO, _Real, 
 2}, {closedtr, _Real, 3}, {normalC, _Real, 2}},
Block[{ptTri, source = point, normal, target, facept, cross, 
 openS = {0., 0., 0.}, closedS = {0., 0., 0.}},
Do[
 ptTri = opentr[[i]];
 normal = normalO[[i]];
 cross = If[Chop[ptTri[[1]] - source, 10^-8] == {0., 0., 0.},
   {target, facept} = {ptTri[[2]], ptTri[[-1]]};
   Cross[normal, facept - target],
   {target, facept} = {ptTri[[1]], ptTri[[-1]]};
   Cross[normal, target - facept]
   ];
 openS += (0.5*cross), {i, 1, Length@normalO}];
Do[
 ptTri = closedtr[[j]];
 normal = normalC[[j]];
 cross = If[Chop[ptTri[[1]] - source, 10^-8] == {0., 0., 0.},
   {target, facept} = {ptTri[[2]], ptTri[[-1]]};
   Cross[normal, facept - target],
   {target, facept} = {ptTri[[1]], ptTri[[-1]]};
   Cross[normal, target - facept]
   ];
 closedS += (0.5*cross), {j, 1, Length@normalC}];
epcc*closedS + epco*openS
], CompilationTarget -> "C"]
]
```